# How to interpret Logcat

Tags: android, logcat

Can anyone tell me how I should read the errors in Logcat? I'd like to understand where my problem is.

At the moment, I tried to read it but can't find the cause of the crash.

Here's the Logcat I don't understand:

```
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paad.whereami/com.paad.whereami.WhereAmI}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at com.paad.whereami.WhereAmI.updateWithNewLocation(WhereAmI.java:290)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at com.paad.whereami.WhereAmI.onCreate(WhereAmI.java:216)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Answer (score 31):

The second "part" of your log is going to be what is important for you in this instance.

> Caused by:
>   `java.lang.NullPointerException`

This means that somewhere in your code something is set to `null` and you are trying to use it as though it isn't.

The next few lines tell you where in your code you can find the error.

> `at com.paad.whereami.WhereAmI.updateWithNewLocation(WhereAmI.java:290)`
>   `at com.paad.whereami.WhereAmI.onCreate(WhereAmI.java:216)`

This should mean that you have a method named `updateWithNewLocation` that you are calling from `onCreate` at line 216. The error is coming from inside this method at line 290. Take a look at line 290 in your code. Whatever you are trying to do on that line is causing the exception because something is `null` that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 5):

**DOCS**

Basic tool from Android to collect/analyse logs is the logcat.

[HERE](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) is the Android's page about logcat

If you use android Studio, you can also check this [LINK](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#systemLogView).

**Capturing**

Basically, you can MANUALLY capture logcat with following command (or just check AndroidMonitor window in AndroidStudio):

```
adb logcat
```

There's a lot of parameters you can add to command which helps you to filter and display the message that you want... This is personal...  I always use the command below to get the message timestamp:

```
adb logcat -v time
```

You can redirect the output to a file and analyze it in a Text Editor.

**Analyzing**

Your app is crashing and you are getting an error like this:

```
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paad.whereami/com.paad.whereami.WhereAmI}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at com.paad.whereami.WhereAmI.updateWithNewLocation(WhereAmI.java:290)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at com.paad.whereami.WhereAmI.onCreate(WhereAmI.java:216)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-18 18:29:44.160: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

This part of the log shows you a lot of information:

**When**

When the issue happened: `05-18 18:29:44.160`

It is important to check when the issue happened... You may find several errors in a log... you must be sure that you are checking the proper messages :)

**Which App**

App which crashed: `com.paad.whereami`

This way, you know which app crashed (to be sure that you are checking the logs about your message)

**Which Error**

ERROR: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

A NULL Pointer Exception error

**Which file is leading to this error**

Usually, we read only the first line of the stack trace. However, your log is a good example that we need to check whole log. In the lines below, we can see were the null pointer happened:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.paad.whereami.WhereAmI.updateWithNewLocation(WhereAmI.java:290)
    at com.paad.whereami.WhereAmI.onCreate(WhereAmI.java:216)
```

Error happened in file `WhereAmI.java`, inside `updateWithNewLocation()` method at line: `290` (stacktrace shows the line that error happened)

**StackTrace**

You can see which method called `updateWithNewLocation()`. This is usefull because sometimes, the error was produced in calling methods. In you example, it was called:

```
at com.paad.whereami.WhereAmI.onCreate(WhereAmI.java:216)
```

etc....

**Overview**

This was just an overview... Not all logs are simple etc... It is just to share the idea and provide a entry-level information to you...

I hope I could help you someway...
Regards