# How to get values from a Arraylist to Buttons?

Tags: java, android, random, arraylist

I'm trying to get random values from a `Arraylist` and then storing it in `Buttons`.
Every time when I run this code with the buttonListRbra my app crashes.

**Here is my code:**

```
    private void generateRandomNumbersRbra()
 {
  int rnd;
  Random rand = new Random();
  int[] randomPick = new int[8];
  ArrayList<Integer> numbersRbra = new ArrayList<Integer>();      
  Button[] buttonListRbra = new Button[8];
  buttonListRbra[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap1);
  buttonListRbra[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap2);
  buttonListRbra[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap3);
  buttonListRbra[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap4);
  buttonListRbra[4] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap5);
  buttonListRbra[5] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap6);
  buttonListRbra[6] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap7);
  buttonListRbra[7] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap8);
  buttonListRbra[8] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap9);    
  for (int i=0 ; i< 8;i++)
  {
   rnd = rand.nextInt(8) + 1;

   if(i==0)
   {
    randomPick[0] = rnd;
    numbersRbra.add(randomPick[0]);
   }
   else
   {
    while(numbersRbra.contains(new Integer(rnd)))
    {
     rnd = rand.nextInt(8) + 1;
    }
    randomPick[i] = rnd;
    numbersRbra.add(randomPick[i]);
   }
  }
 }
```

logCat:

> 05-07 14:15:50.325: D/libEGL(10749): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
>   05-07 14:15:50.355: D/libEGL(10749): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
>   05-07 14:15:50.360: D/libEGL(10749): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
>   05-07 14:15:50.370: E/(10749): Device driver API match
>   05-07 14:15:50.370: E/(10749): Device driver API version: 23
>   05-07 14:15:50.370: E/(10749): User space API version: 23 
>   05-07 14:15:50.370: E/(10749): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013 
>   05-07 14:15:50.490: D/OpenGLRenderer(10749): Enabling debug mode 0
>   05-07 14:15:54.010: D/AndroidRuntime(10749): Shutting down VM
>   05-07 14:15:54.010: W/dalvikvm(10749): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bdc700)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    ... 11 more
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=8
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at com.roc.quickynumbers.GameActivity.generateRandomNumbersRbra(GameActivity.java:73)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    at com.roc.quickynumbers.GameActivity.startGame(GameActivity.java:46)
>   05-07 14:15:54.015: E/AndroidRuntime(10749):    ... 14 more

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Thanks everyone. I got it working now!

Solution:

```
int rnd;
    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> numbersRbra = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Button[] buttonListRbra = new Button[9];
    buttonListRbra[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap1);
    buttonListRbra[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap2);
    buttonListRbra[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap3);
    buttonListRbra[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap4);
    buttonListRbra[4] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap5);
    buttonListRbra[5] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap6);
    buttonListRbra[6] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap7);
    buttonListRbra[7] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap8);
    buttonListRbra[8] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap9);

    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) // Loop through your entire list to access all your 9 Buttons
    {
        rnd = rand.nextInt(9) + 1; // Return an int in the range [1,9] => 9 elements

        if(i==0)
        {
           numbersRbra.add(rnd);
           buttonListRbra[i].setText(numbersRbra.get(i).toString()); //Set the Button Text for the first iteration too
        }
        else
        {
          while(numbersRbra.contains(rnd)) // Transformation between Integer and int done automatically
          {
              rnd = rand.nextInt(9) + 1; // Return an int in the range [1,9]
          }
          numbersRbra.add(rnd);
          buttonListRbra[i].setText(numbersRbra.get(i).toString()); // Set it after finding the correct number
        }
      }
```

Comment: array with 8 element cannot contain 9 element, check sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't understand correctly the `Array`.

When you create an array like that : `new Button[8];`.

It can contain 8 element. The allocated array will start at index 0 and stop at index 7.
So if you want to store 9 elements like you do, do something like that:

```
Button[] buttonListRbra = new Button[9];
```

And loop correctly through it.

The logcat confirm this error. You have an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You are trying to access an index wich is bigger than the size of the array. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065258/how-to-interpret-logcat) to detect the errors from the LogCat yourself.

**Edit:**

Here is the corrected code that i think you want:

```
      int rnd;
      Random rand = new Random();
      ArrayList<Integer> numbersRbra = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      Button[] buttonListRbra = new Button[9];
      buttonListRbra[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap1);
      buttonListRbra[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap2);
      buttonListRbra[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap3);
      buttonListRbra[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap4);
      buttonListRbra[4] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap5);
      buttonListRbra[5] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap6);
      buttonListRbra[6] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap7);
      buttonListRbra[7] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap8);
      buttonListRbra[8] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap9);

      for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) // Loop through your entire list to access all your 9 Buttons
      {
          rnd = rand.nextInt(9) + 1; // Return an int in the range [1,9] => 9 elements

          if(i==0)
          {
              numbersRbra.add(rnd);
              buttonListRbra[i].setText(numbersRbra.get(i)); // Set the Button Text for the first iteration too
          }
          else
          {
              while(numbersRbra.contains(rnd)) // Transformation between Integer and int done automatically
              {
                  rnd = rand.nextInt(9) + 1; // Return an int in the range [1,9]
              }
              numbersRbra.add(rnd);
              buttonListRbra[i].setText(numbersRbra.get(i)); // Set it after finding the correct number
          }
      }
```

I strongly recommend that you understand the code first before using it and learn a bit about how to use the [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html). As i have already said in my first answer, you should try to understand the error the [LogCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065258/how-to-interpret-logcat) provide you. It can only helps you in your future applications.

Comment: Thanks this fixed the error. i made the mistake by making randomPick[8] and setting the same number to new Button[8] (now 9)

Comment: @daxcyy I have updated my answer to make your code functionnal. Hope you can understand it and learn from it :)

Comment: Thanks alot! I got it working now but i had to add a little of code. I added: .toString() to put it in mu buttons, I will post the solution above!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an `int` (primitive data type) into a List of `Integer` (Hullclass). 
Try adding `Integer.valueof(randomPick[i])`.
Next time, please include Logcat output in your post, so we can read the stacktrace.
Also, I think you dont need the Array you are using. Just insert the values into the List immediately.

Edit: Above posts are right, you are also creating an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` by accessing field 9 of an Array which is only 8 fields long.
You should consider reading the error log to find such errors by yourself the next time.

Edit:
You are basically doing

`randomPick[i] = rnd;
numbersRbra.add(randomPick[i]);`

but instead you can just

`numbersRbra.add(rnd);`

You don't youse the `randomPick[]` somewhere else and hence are filling an Array and a List with the same random values for no particular reason (I guess).

If you then want to set the Label of the Button to the generated random number, you
simply call `buttonListRbra[i].setText(numbersRbra.get(i));`.

Comment: How do you mean i dont need the array list? and i posted my logcat

Comment: Thanks, but how can i now set the values of the arraylist to my buttons, im not good with arraylists as you already noticed

Comment: I have edited my post again to answer your additional question.

Comment: I have edited my post, can you check it please and tell me what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
 Button[] buttonListRbra = new Button[8];
  buttonListRbra[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap1);
  buttonListRbra[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap2);
  buttonListRbra[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap3);
  buttonListRbra[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap4);
  buttonListRbra[4] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap5);
  buttonListRbra[5] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap6);
  buttonListRbra[6] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap7);
  buttonListRbra[7] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap8);
  buttonListRbra[8] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tap9);
```

You are creating an array that can hold 8 button references  from index 0 to 7, and after that you are trying to access the button at 8 index, but index 8 does not exist i.e it is out of bounds from the array's perspective, so you are getting exception while trying to execute `buttonListRbra[8]`.