# Invalid float after new Decimal Format

Tags: java, android, floating-point, decimal

User want to raise temperature from EditText "set_temp". 
Currtemp is global string means current temperature

```
float temp = Float.parseFloat(set_temp.getText().toString());
temp-=0.1;
currTemp=new DecimalFormat("#0.0").format(temp);
set_temp.setText(currTemp);
```

After this i have an error in logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.unn.caminlab, PID: 7835
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "49,9"
```

// but why?

Comment: `,` comma instead of `.` fullstop maybe

Comment: the sad irony is that the answer is just one line above his question :(

Comment: @svarog I assume its coming from user input, as nothing else would produce a comma. Reading logs is a useful skill to start with. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065258/how-to-interpret-logcat

Comment: `set_temp.getText().toString()` is the culprit, he should at least catch the exception and move on

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are parsing a text field, that contains an invalid decimal format.

```
 float temp = Float.parseFloat(set_temp.getText().toString());
```

your `set_temp` field contains `"49,9"` when it should be `"49.9"`

I assume they can type into the field. You need to restrict it to a number only field. Not plain text. (to rid `,` input)

Add this to your xml for the field:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Comment: android:inputType="numberDecimal" doesn't solve the problem. DecimalFormat is (0.0) but after i have 0,0 in my field...

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if user having US English language locale, in many cases, user may include float literals language specific.

2) Remove set_temp.getText().toString() from Float.parseFloat() and check set_temp.getText().toString() is returning correct number string literal and then pass it to parseInt().